# how to update a route within a cypress.io test and have a react-router based app change state without refreshing the whole page?

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

I am testing a react-router application (that uses chunk based response) using cypress.io. I need to navigate to a page and when I use cy.visit() it throws an error 404 Page Not found. I guess why I am getting this error is because the page i snot an html page and cy.visit() loads on a html page. So o how can I navigate to that particular page in such case?

Comment: Hi, is it your application? I mean do you start application on your local?

Comment: No, the application is live url and not on local.